# Como enviar o formulário sem redirecionar pra outra página em PHP

Tags: php

Como fazer com que envie o formulário por traz sem redirecionar pra outra página apenas limpar os campos e exibir um alerta ou mensagem de que foi enviado, sem dar refresh na página, pois eu fiz assim :

```
echo ("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>window.location.href='index.php';window.alert('Formulário enviado com sucesso!');</SCRIPT>");
```

Mas ainda tem um delay que mostra a aplicação rodando e depois mostra o alerta e por último carrega a página.

Comment: Estude sobre AJAX. Aqui mesmo no site há [muitas perguntas sobre isso](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ajax).

Comment: Pode estudar sobre o [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) do JavaScript também.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ola você pode fazer com `Ajax`, assim:

```
    $.ajax({
        // URL de destino
        url: 'index.php',
        type: 'post',
        // Suas variaveis serializadas EX: 'nome=Bruno&idade=24'
        data: dataString,
        cache: false,

        success: function (data)
        {
            // retorno do php
            alert('Formulário enviado com sucesso!');
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Para mudar o comportamento do Submit. Da uma olhada em Prevent Default. Você disabilita o comportamento do submit de recarregar a tela, e na função faz o que tem que fazer (alert, limpar campos, etc)

https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault